# Mount file systems from complete disk image with several partitions and logical volumes

Tags: linux, lvm, mount, fdisk

I have a complete disk image (dd if=/dev/sda of=foo.bin) that contains several partitions and LVM logical volumes on which there are ext4 filesystems. How do I mount one of the filesystems on this diskimage?

I have the output of fdisk -l from when the image was made.

I assume I have to use a loopback device somehow, but I am not sure how to do it when I have the entire device as an image and not just one filesystem.

Hope you can help.

Operating system is Linux.

Answer (score 3):

Try to use `kpartx`, which will export the partitions on the image as device nodes, which you can simply mount.

1. Get the list of available partitions with `kpartx -l imagefile`.
2. Activate the mapping with `kpartx -a imagefile`
3. Mount the partition. The nodes are in `/dev/mapper`.
4. Do stuff.
5. Unmount.
6. Unmap with `kpartx -d imagefile`.

For more infos, see `man kpartx`.

Answer (score 0):

it can be done out of the box using a combination of fdisk and dd.
First, use fdisk's p command to show partition boundaries, then do

```
dd if=device-image.bin of=partition-image.bin skip=<number in Start column> count=<number in Sectors column>
```